# Get cookie/localStorage value in nextjs API request

Tags: reactjs, api, cookies, local-storage, next.js

I'm trying to get cookie or localStorage value in my API request. When I'm trying to access localStorage I get error that localStorage is not defined, cookies are undefined, I tried my luck with AsyncLocalStorage, but I'm getting error that window is undefined. There is any way to get saved value in this asynchronous function?

```
import AsyncLocalStorage from '@createnextapp/async-local-storage'

export default async (req, res) => {
try {
let data = await AsyncLocalStorage.getItem('@key')
console.log(data)
}catch(error){
console.log(error)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected. When you process the data in your API it is actually running in the server. Localstorage, and cookies however are browser based storage (This is also why window is undefined, servers don't have windows). As a result they are not available to the API to leverage. Instead when you make the API request you need to add the data into a header which can then be parsed on your server.

Setting a header on your request:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader

From there you should be able to read the headers through:

```
(req, res) => {

   // look at all these great headers we have
   const { headers } = req;

}
```